Using Jwt and cookies together for authentication
I have managed to create the jwt token, but I am not sure where should I store it. I have seen many online websites talking about storing the jwt token in the cookie, but I not sure if it is the right approach as I thought normally the jwt token should be stored in the header inside the authorization parameter. I have the below code in AccountController to use cookies, but I am not sure how to include the jwt token inside.
if (login.Password.Equals(passwordCheck) && login.Username.Equals(adminCheck))
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim("Role", "Admin")
    };

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
        claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}

and I have the below code in Program.cs to add cookie and jwt, and according to some online article about using both jwt and cookie:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Issuer"),
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Audience"),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:SecretKey"))),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300),
        RequireExpirationTime = true
    };
});

Using ASP.NET MVC, I have multiple actions in the controller that has Http Request such as (and I am not sure if I should use ValidateAntiForgeryToken instead of jwt token):
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> GetActivationCode(string id)
{
    var actCode = (await _productService.GetProduct(id)).ActivationCode;
    return actCode;
}

but I am not sure how to use jwt token to authenticate for these ajax calls from the views:
$.ajax({
    url: '/Product/GetActivationCode',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $("#actCodeText").text("Activation Code: " + response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)
I tried referring to multiple online articles such as this: Combining cookie and jwt authentication, but I keep getting this error:
SignInAsync when principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false is not allowed when AuthenticationOptions.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn is true.

For using JWT Token necessary to add Authorization Headers to you request.
$.ajax({
    url: '/point', 
    method: 'GET', Any (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer   ${jwtToken}`
    },
    success: function(response) {
     
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       
    }
}); 

In order to use JWT only your action GetActivationCode add this attribute.
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<string> GetActivationCode(string id)
{
    var actCode = (await _productService.GetProduct(id)).ActivationCode;
    return actCode;
}


Hi @ISR, thank you very much for the answer, can I know where I can get the value of jwtToken in cshtml file?

@jett you have to implement jwt service for a token write (https://medium.com/@darshana-edirisinghe/jwt-security-concerns-f79e63ff4871) and then pass  a token to View any convenient approach (request, ViewData, etc)

Hi @ISR, really thank you very much, everything kinda works now, just asking, what about adding the headers when submitting a form? is it still use ajax to do that?
